# SSRS report renders differently after page 1

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am creating a label report but am having an issue with how the report is displayed after page 1.

The report is sized to reflect the label size, and each label contains an address and some images regarding postage.

When the report is viewed in the preview pane, or on the report server, the first page displays as expected, but on each page after, the label contents have all been shifted to the top edge.

[image]

[image]

As you can see, there is now, no visible space between the top of the label and the label contents. This causes each label after the 1st to print slightly differently, and I would like to rectify this.

There does not seem to be any property that that changes this behavior, so any ideas would be of great help.

Comment: The preview mode is often inaccurate with regards to displaying correct formatting.  Does it look the same if you export to .pdf or view it in print mode?

Comment: can you show the design screen as well? Try setting the report property.. consume container white space to true.no headers and make sure your object location is set at 0

Comment: @Harry consume container white space does not appear to make any difference. What do you mean by object location? I tried to add a page header, which does keep a gap at the top of each page, but it creates a bigger gap for the 1st page! Must be a common answer to getting each page to display in the same way?

Comment: By object I meant the tablix.. ensure it's at 0 location.. remove all headers as well. when you export to PDF do you notice the gap on the second page?

Comment: @Harry there is a gap on the first label in preview mode, on the browser, and when exported to pdf, word etc. All subsequent labels there is no gap in preview mode, browser, and when exported.